# Facebook Android - Too Many Server Redirects Error

Tags: 2.2-froyo, facebook

I have posted a bit.ly link on Facebook, which got converted to an epi.us link (it was an epicurious.com link to begin with). Everything works as normal in most cases, but on the Facebook Android app, there is an error when I click on the link. It states:

> Data Connectivity Problem - The page contains too many server redirects

This is with the latest update to Facebook (just updated today 12/8/11). I am running Android 2.2 (Froyo). Is this something that can be fixed by using a different url shortener?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably doing something like `m.facebook.com` -> `facebook.com` -> `bit.ly` -> `epi.us` -> `epicurious.com`, which *is* a fair number of redirects.  You could try a different browser that might have a longer limit or you could just post the link directly.  Unlike Twitter you don't need to shorten URLs for Facebook most of the time.  At minimum you could remove the `epi.us` step.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried removing the epi.us step (there is a way to disable that in bit.ly). Unfortunately, the problem persists. If it happened in more operating systems, I could explain the problem to my manager. But since it is only happening in Android, it is something that I must fix. Any other suggestions?